# HP Probook 440 - cannot connect to 2 external monitors (using Ugreen USB type C hub)

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I'm using HP Probook 440 G6,

When I connect to 1 external monitor through, it works well

But when I try to connect to 2 external monitors, it stop working, no signal go to both external monitor

How could I make my laptop show output to 2 external monitors, or, where could I check on laptop's specification whether it support max 1 or 2 external monitor?

Comment: I had a similar problem on my business class HP laptop and my buddy's too.  It is going to sound crazy but I was successful after "goofing with" the Intel graphics control panel thingy.  I went around in circles a few times but I was able to accomplish what the windows display settings would not let me do.  I don't know if this will do it for you but it is worth a shot.  I also could NOT get three displays working.. with the two external, the laptop display was disabled.  I think this is what the intel tool let me do and windows did not.

Comment: I think I'm good with only 2 external monitors instead of 1 14" laptop monitor + 1 24" external monitor, 
How did you make it showed up on 2 external monitors?

Comment: As I mentioned in my pervious comment, use the Intel Graphics Control Panel.  Don't give up too soon.  Keep playing with the settings here and you may succeed.